# Most approprite place for storing registration info in the registry

Tags: windows, licensing, registry

I'm aware that any licensing registry key can be detected using monitoring tools, just want to secure it against ordinary users. 
What places of registry look fit for storing a key?

Answer (score 0):

`HKLM\Software\<YourCompany>\<TheApp>`

Anywhere else borders on the malicious.